# Clip raster by mask layer

Tags: python, raster, qgis

I have a SPOT VGT raster image downloaded from terrascope  , and I want to clip it by a mask layer but I think the raster is not displayed correctly. It's bigger than others and the mask does not cover the desired area. When I open it in QGIS I get the "the raster has no coordinate reference system set" icon, so I chose one (WGS 84 EPSG:4326) (the icon disappeared) but when I add the mask layer of the same CRS I get what displayed in the image above.[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCTlt.png)

Link to the raster : <services.terrascope.be/download/SPOTVGT/C3/FreeS10/V2/2012/20120421/2_20120421S10_Europe_RADIO/2.20120421S10_Europe_B3.HDF>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community My problem is that when I open the raster in QGIS it doesn't display in the correct area which is over the Mediterranean zone compared to the Google satellite map, (I changed the CRS but it did nothing)